# if we create any method in a class in python, we always use self as first argument, but while calling that method we dont pass? why?

Tags: python, self

```
class ABC:
    def xyz(self):
        print "in xyz"

obj = ABC()
print obj.xyz()
```

output : `in xyz`

here `self` is not given as parameter while calling `xyz` with `obj`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `self` is, by default, *the instance itself*. `obj.xyz()` is equivalent to `ABC.xyz(obj)`.

Comment: Not as explicit as some people might want it, but still +1

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of every class method, including `__init__`, is always a reference to the current instance of the class.

By convention, this argument is always named `self`.

In the `__init__` method, self refers to the newly created object; in other *instance methods*, it refers to the instance whose method was called. Although you need to specify `self` explicitly when defining the method, you do not specify it when calling the method; Python will add it for you automatically.

Learn more about `self` [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019627/python-self-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is what happens:

1. It tries to evaluate `obj.xyz`
2. It funds that the object `obj` has no attribute named `xyz`
3. It then looks in `obj`'s class (`ABC`) for an attribute named `xyz`, which it does have
4. `ABC.xyz` is a function, so then it "wraps" it into a "instance method". Basically, `ABC.xyz` is a function with one parameter (`self`), so the "instance method" is a function with one less parameter from the original function (no parameters in this case), which remembers the object `obj`. And if you call this "instance method", it passes it onto `ABC.xyz`, with the first argument being `obj`, the rest of the arguments being the argument to the bound method.
5. `obj.xyz` evaluates to this instance method
6. You make a call on this instance method, which calls `ABC.xyz`, with the remembered instance (`obj`) as the first argument.

Here are the relevant parts from the language reference (scroll from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)):

> Class instances
>
> A class instance is created by calling a class object (see above). A class instance has a namespace implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the first place in which attribute references are searched. When an
>   attribute is not found there, and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search continues with the class
>   attributes. If a class attribute is found that is a user-defined
>   function object, it is transformed into an instance method object
>   whose `__self__` attribute is the instance. [...]

and

> Instance methods
>
> [...]
>
> When an instance method object is created by retrieving a user-defined
>   function object from a class via one of its instances, its `__self__`
>   attribute is the instance, and the method object is said to be bound.
>   The new method’s `__func__` attribute is the original function object.
>
> [...]
>
> When an instance method object is called, the underlying function
>   (`__func__`) is called, inserting the class instance (`__self__`) in
>   front of the argument list. For instance, when `C` is a class which
>   contains a definition for a function `f()`, and `x` is an instance of
>   `C`, calling `x.f(1)` is equivalent to calling `C.f(x, 1)`.
>
> [...]

Answer (score 0):

In the backend of the code `obj.xyz()`. The parameter returned is object(obj) itself that means `ABC.xyz(obj)`