# designing a python class

Tags: python, class

I'm learning about classes and design in Python, and I have a question of how to implement the following pattern:

I would like the class to initialise with some code, some of which I would like to be able to call later on via a function, e.g.:

```
class c:
    def __init__(self):
        print('1')
        m()

    def m(self):
        print('2')
        print('3')
```

I am after something like the above, but I cannot use m() in **init** as it will not have been declared at this point. Is there anyway of implementing this without having to use the same code twice?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `self.m()`

```
class c:
    def __init__(self):
        print('1')
        self.m()

    def m(self):
        print('2')
        print('3')
```

Answer (score 2):

> cannot use m() in init as it will not have been declared at this point

This is not the case. Python's execution does not work that way; it will not care where the `m` definition is until it is actually needed.

The reason you got an error is because there [is no "implicit this" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019627/python-self-keyword); writing `m` here looks for the *global* `m` and *not* a method `m` belonging to the instance. Just as you must accept an explicit `self` parameter, so you must explicitly look for methods on `self`: thus, `self.m()`.

Answer (score -1):

You may be looking at `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod` decorators.

```py
class c:
    def __init__(self):
        print('1')
        m()

    @staticmethod
    def m():
        # You don't rely on any class method initialised attributes
        print('2')
        print('3')

    @classmethod
    def m(cls):
        # You may use cls to refer to the class itself
        print('2')
        print('3')
```

You can choose which suits your case better for your particular method.

Both would allow you to call a function as `c.m()`